# How to group pandas DataFrame entries by date in a non-unique column

Tags: python, pandas

A Pandas `DataFrame` contains column named `"date"` that contains non-unique `datetime` values. 
I can group the lines in this frame using:

```
data.groupby(data['date'])
```

However, this splits the data by the `datetime` values. I would like to group these data by the year stored in the "date" column. [This page](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/?p=125) shows how to group by year in cases where the time stamp is used as an index, which is not true in my case.

How do I achieve this grouping?

Comment: For those coming here in 2017+, there are several new ways to groupby a particular amount of time. [See this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47140458/3707607)

Answer (score 137, accepted):

I'm using pandas 0.16.2. This has better performance on my large dataset:

```
data.groupby(data.date.dt.year)
```

Using the `dt` option and playing around with `weekofyear`, `dayofweek` etc. becomes far easier.

Comment: Concur, this seems to be the pandaic way of accessing date attributes for a series.

Answer (score 81):

ecatmur's solution will work fine. This will be better performance on large datasets, though:

```
data.groupby(data['date'].map(lambda x: x.year))
```

Comment: Why map instead of apply?

Comment: Afaik, `map` usually has some good efficiency qualities when applying arbitrary functions as compared to just using `apply`.

Answer (score 45):

This might be easier to explain with a sample dataset.

**Create Sample Data**

Let's assume we have a single column of Timestamps, `date` and another column we would like to perform an aggregation on, `a`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.DatetimeIndex(['2012-1-1', '2012-6-1', '2015-1-1', '2015-2-1', '2015-3-1']),
                   'a':[9,5,1,2,3]}, columns=['date', 'a'])

df

        date  a
0 2012-01-01  9
1 2012-06-01  5
2 2015-01-01  1
3 2015-02-01  2
4 2015-03-01  3
```

There are several ways to group by year

- Use the dt accessor with `year` property
- Put `date` in index and use anonymous function to access year
- Use `resample` method
- Convert to pandas Period

#### `.dt` accessor with `year` property

When you have a column (and not an index) of pandas Timestamps, you can access many more extra properties and methods with the `dt` accessor. For instance:

```
df['date'].dt.year

0    2012
1    2012
2    2015
3    2015
4    2015
Name: date, dtype: int64
```

We can use this to form our groups and calculate some aggregations on a particular column:

```
df.groupby(df['date'].dt.year)['a'].agg(['sum', 'mean', 'max'])

      sum  mean  max
date                
2012   14     7    9
2015    6     2    3
```

---

#### put date in index and use anonymous function to access year

If you set the date column as the index, it becomes a DateTimeIndex with the same properties and methods as the `dt` accessor gives normal columns

```
df1 = df.set_index('date')
df1.index.year

Int64Index([2012, 2012, 2015, 2015, 2015], dtype='int64', name='date')
```

Interestingly, when using the groupby method, you can pass it a function. This function will be implicitly passed the DataFrame's index. So, we can get the same result from above with the following:

```
df1.groupby(lambda x: x.year)['a'].agg(['sum', 'mean', 'max'])

      sum  mean  max
2012   14     7    9
2015    6     2    3
```

---

#### Use the `resample` method

If your date column is not in the index, you must specify the column with the `on` parameter. You also need to specify the [offset alias](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) as a string.

```
df.resample('AS', on='date')['a'].agg(['sum', 'mean', 'max'])

             sum  mean  max
date                       
2012-01-01  14.0   7.0  9.0
2013-01-01   NaN   NaN  NaN
2014-01-01   NaN   NaN  NaN
2015-01-01   6.0   2.0  3.0
```

---

#### Convert to pandas Period

You can also convert the date column to a pandas Period object. We must pass in the offset alias as a string to determine the length of the Period.

```
df['date'].dt.to_period('A')

0   2012
1   2012
2   2015
3   2015
4   2015
Name: date, dtype: object
```

We can then use this as a group

```
df.groupby(df['date'].dt.to_period('Y'))['a'].agg(['sum', 'mean', 'max'])


      sum  mean  max
2012   14     7    9
2015    6     2    3
```

Comment: In the last method where you use `to_period('A')`, what is that ('A') for?

Comment: @Shiv_90 the `'A'` is a timeseries offset-alias: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases

Comment: Which method would you recommend if one needs a separate 'date' column to be saved as well? For example, if I run the simple `.dt.year` method and save it in a new data frame, the dates are saved as indices and that becomes problematic if say I need to plot the data because the 'dates' column is not really there but only the three provided in `.agg()`

Answer (score 15):

This should work:

```
data.groupby(lambda x: data['date'][x].year)
```

Answer (score 1):

this will also work

`data.groupby(data['date'].dt.year)`

Comment: Should work but when executed it outputs the location of the object in the memory but no real output. `<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x10d7f6438>` is what I get when executed.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
data.groupby(['col1', data.date.dt.year]).agg({'col2': 'agg_func'}).reset_index()
```

In case you want to group by year from datetime column and also by another different type column (col1)