# Grouping data in a dataframe to produce lists against unique ids in Pandas/Python

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am using the pandas/python and have a dataframe along the following lines:

```
21627   red
21627   green
21627   red
21627   blue
21627   purple
21628   yellow
21628   red
21628   green
21629   red
21629   red
```

Which I want to reduce to:

```
21627   red, green, blue, purple
21628   yellow, red, green
21629   red
```

Whats the best way of doing this (and collapsing all values in lists to unique values)?

Also, if I wanted to keep the redundancy:

```
21627   red, green, red, blue, purple
21628   yellow, red, green
21629   red, red
```

Whats the best way of achieving this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391969/how-to-group-pandas-dataframe-entries-by-date-in-a-non-unique-column) and tutorial [here](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/?p=125)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you *really* wanted to do this you could use a groupby apply:

```
In [11]: df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: list(set(x['colours'])))
Out[11]: 
id
21627    [blue, purple, green, red]
21628          [green, red, yellow]
21629                         [red]
dtype: object

In [12]: df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: list(x['colours']))
Out[12]: 
id
21627    [red, green, red, blue, purple]
21628               [yellow, red, green]
21629                         [red, red]
dtype: object
```

However, DataFrames containing lists are not particularly efficient.

[Pivot table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tools.pivot.pivot_table.html) gets you a more useful DataFrame:

```
In [21]: df.pivot_table(rows='id', cols='colours', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
Out[21]: 
colours  blue  green  purple  red  yellow
id                                       
21627       1      1       1    2       0
21628       0      1       0    1       1
21629       0      0       0    2       0
```

My favourite function `get_dummies` lets you do it but not as elegantly or efficiently (but I'll keep this original, if crazy, suggestion):

```
In [22]: pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('id')['colours']).reset_index().groupby('id').sum()
Out[22]: 
       blue  green  purple  red  yellow
id                                     
21627     1      1       1    2       0
21628     0      1       0    1       1
21629     0      0       0    2       0
```

Comment: mabye add to cookbook these types of recipes

Comment: Hey Andy, thanks - I am going to use the lists against each ID as a table to index in a search engine - hence wanted the lists of keywords against each ID

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way; Though @Andy's a bit more intuitve

```
In [24]: df.groupby('id').apply(
              lambda x: x['color'].value_counts()).unstack().fillna(0)
Out[24]: 
       blue  green  purple  red  yellow
id                                     
21627     1      1       1    2       0
21628     0      1       0    1       1
21629     0      0       0    2       0
```

Comment: That's not how you spell color :p, `value_counts` makes it more intuitive, but I think `pivot_table` is the way to do it.

Comment: I agree ``pivot_table`` is better; (this is basically what it does internally anyhow); I always though ``colour`` was a colloquial spelling (deprecated) :)