# Computing cumulative values for each year of a dataframe separately

Tags: python, pandas

I have the foll. pandas dataframe with datetime index:

```
datetime       VAL
2000-01-01   -283.0000
2000-01-02   -283.0000
2000-01-03    -10.6710
2000-01-04    -12.2700
2000-01-05    -10.7855
2001-01-06     -9.1480
2001-01-07     -9.5300
2001-01-08    -10.4675
2001-01-09    -10.9205
2001-01-10    -11.5715
```

I would like to compute cumulative values for each year and replace the VAL column by the cumulative values. E.g, It will look something like this:

```
datetime       VAL
2000-01-01   -283.0000
2000-01-02   -283.0000 + -283.0000
2000-01-03    -10.6710 + -283.0000 + -283.0000
2000-01-04    -12.2700 + -10.6710 + -283.0000 + -283.0000
2000-01-05    -10.7855 + -12.2700 + -10.6710 + -283.0000 + -283.0000
2001-01-06     -9.1480
2001-01-07     -9.5300 + -9.5300
2001-01-08    -10.4675 + -10.4675
2001-01-09    -10.9205 + -10.9205
2001-01-10    -11.5715 + -11.5715
```

I haven't done the actual calculations which is why you see -283.000 + -283.000 instead of -566.0000

Not sure how to proceed with this, I could do a groupby and then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the year via `.year` on a DateTimeIndex, and pass that to `groupby`:

```
>>> df["cumulative_VAL"] = df.groupby(df.index.year)["VAL"].cumsum()
>>> df
                 VAL  cumulative_VAL
datetime                            
2000-01-01 -283.0000       -283.0000
2000-01-02 -283.0000       -566.0000
2000-01-03  -10.6710       -576.6710
2000-01-04  -12.2700       -588.9410
2000-01-05  -10.7855       -599.7265
2001-01-06   -9.1480         -9.1480
2001-01-07   -9.5300        -18.6780
2001-01-08  -10.4675        -29.1455
2001-01-09  -10.9205        -40.0660
2001-01-10  -11.5715        -51.6375
```

Comment: thanks @DSM, is there a difference between doing `df.groupby(df.index.year)["VAL"].cumsum()` and `df['VAL'].groupby(df.index.year).cumsum()`?

Comment: @user308827: not here, or least not that I can think of offhand.  In both cases you've selected the column VAL before you apply any operations.

Answer (score 1):

Use `numpy.cumsum()`

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
>>> a array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
>>> np.cumsum(a) array([ 1,  3,  6, 10, 15, 21])
>>> np.cumsum(a, dtype=float)     # specifies type of output value(s) array([  1.,   3.,   6.,  10.,  15.,  21.])
```

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html

To `groupby` year, you can use:

```
data.groupby(data['datetime'].map(lambda x: x.year))
```

[How to group pandas DataFrame entries by date in a non-unique column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391969/how-to-group-pandas-dataframe-entries-by-date-in-a-non-unique-column)

Comment: thanks @drum, cumsum works but how to use it along with groupby?