# missing date columns in pandas dataframe after using groupby

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which I am creating by reading an Excel file:

```
Project Release Name    Cycle Name  Cycle Start Date    Cycle End Date  Exec Date   Planned Exec Date   Available Test Cases    Planned Tested  Passed  Failed  Blocked No Run  Tester
B1  Y1  CM1 2/7/2018    2/20/2018   2/6/2018    2/6/2018    2   10  8   8   0   0   0   Tester3
B1  Y1  CM1 2/7/2018    2/20/2018   2/7/2018    2/7/2018    2   13  10  9   1   1   0   Tester3
B1  Y1  CM1 2/7/2018    2/20/2018   2/8/2018    2/8/2018    0   1   1   1   0   0   0   Tester3
B1  Y1  CM1 2/7/2018    2/20/2018   2/9/2018    2/9/2018    0   2   2   2   0   0   0   Tester3
B1  Y1  CM1 2/7/2018    2/20/2018   2/10/2018   2/10/2018   0   2   2   2   0   0   0   Tester3
B1  Y1  CL1 2/7/2018    2/25/2018   2/1/2018    2/1/2018    5   25  20  20  0   0   0   Tester 4
B1  Y1  CL1 2/7/2018    2/25/2018   2/2/2018    2/2/2018    10  30  20  18  2   0   0   Tester 4
B1  Y1  CL1 2/7/2018    2/25/2018   2/3/2018    2/3/2018    0   2   2   0   2   0   0   Tester 4
B1  Y1  CL1 1/17/2018   2/25/2018   2/4/2018    2/4/2018    0   3   3   1   2   0   0   Tester 4
B1  Y1  CL1 1/17/2018   2/25/2018   2/5/2018    2/5/2018    5   32  25  20  4   1   0   Tester 4
C1  Z1  CK1 1/10/2018   2/20/2018   2/3/2018    2/3/2018    0   1   1   0   1   0   0   Tester5
C1  Z1  CK1 1/10/2018   2/20/2018   2/4/2018    2/4/2018    0   1   1   0   1   0   0   Tester5
C1  Z1  CK1 1/10/2018   2/20/2018   2/5/2018    2/5/2018    0   1   1   0   1   0   0   Tester5
C1  Z1  CK1 1/10/2018   2/20/2018   2/6/2018    2/6/2018    0   1   1   1   0   0   0   Tester5
C1  Z1  CK1 1/10/2018   2/20/2018   2/7/2018    2/7/2018    0   1   1   1   0   0   0   Tester6
C1  Z1  CK1 1/10/2018   2/20/2018   2/8/2018    2/8/2018    0   1   1   1   0   0   0   Tester6
C1  Z1  CK2 1/17/2018   2/18/2018   2/6/2018    2/6/2018    0   1   1   1   0   0   0   Tester6
C1  Z1  CK2 1/17/2018   2/18/2018   2/7/2018    2/7/2018    0   2   2   0   2   0   0   Tester6
C1  Z1  CK2 1/17/2018   2/18/2018   2/8/2018    2/8/2018    0   2   2   0   2   0   0   Tester7
C1  Z1  CK2 1/17/2018   2/18/2018   2/9/2018    2/9/2018    0   2   2   0   2   0   0   Tester7
C1  Z1  CK2 1/17/2018   2/18/2018   2/10/2018   2/10/2018   0   2   2   1   1   0   0   Tester7
C1  Z1  CK2 1/17/2018   2/18/2018   2/11/2018   2/11/2018   0   2   2   2   0   0   0   Tester7
```

And I am using pandas groupby as follows:

```
dx1 = pd.read_excel('Trend.xlsx',sheetname='Execution by Date')

dx1 = dx1.groupby(['Project', 'Release Name', 'Cycle Name', 'Cycle Start Date',
       'Cycle End Date'])['Exec Date','Planned Exec Date', 'Available Test Cases', 'Planned', 'Tested', 'Passed', 'Failed',
       'Blocked'].sum().reset_index()
```

and here is the result I get:

```
Project Release Name    Cycle Name  Cycle Start Date    Cycle End Date  Available Test Cases    Planned Tested  Passed  Failed  Blocked
B1  Y1  CL1 2018-01-17 00:00:00 2018-02-25 00:00:00 5   35  28  21  6   1
B1  Y1  CL1 2018-02-07 00:00:00 2018-02-25 00:00:00 15  57  42  38  4   0
B1  Y1  CM1 2018-02-07 00:00:00 2018-02-20 00:00:00 4   28  23  22  1   1
C1  Z1  CK1 2018-01-10 00:00:00 2018-02-20 00:00:00 0   6   6   3   3   0
C1  Z1  CK2 2018-01-17 00:00:00 2018-02-18 00:00:00 0   11  11  4   7   0
```

As you can see that, 'Exec Date' and 'Planned Exec Date' are missing.

How can I bring both of the missing date columns back into the dataframe. 
I have tried all seemingly relevant solutions but none worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve]. In addition, please read through: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You're grouping by

```
['Project', 'Release Name', 'Cycle Name', 'Cycle Start Date', 'Cycle End Date']
```

for which each combination have multiple different values for `Exec Date` and `Planned Exec Date`. In other words, you have e.g. 3 different values, and you can only keep one. Seems like `groupby()` will not choose any of them for you, and simply leave the column out of the result. You can do it manually, however, and then merge them into your `groupby()` results:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option("display.width", 300)
import sys

# Read in data set
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

test_data = StringIO("""Project;Release Name;Cycle Name;Cycle Start Date;Cycle End Date;Exec Date;Planned Exec Date;Available Test Cases;Planned;Tested;Passed;Failed;Blocked;No Run;Tester
        B1;Y1;CM1;2/7/2018;2/20/2018;2/6/2018;2/6/2018;2;10;8;8;0;0;0;Tester3
        B1;Y1;CM1;2/7/2018;2/20/2018;2/7/2018;2/7/2018;2;13;10;9;1;1;0;Tester3
        B1;Y1;CM1;2/7/2018;2/20/2018;2/8/2018;2/8/2018;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;Tester3
        B1;Y1;CM1;2/7/2018;2/20/2018;2/9/2018;2/9/2018;0;2;2;2;0;0;0;Tester3
        B1;Y1;CM1;2/7/2018;2/20/2018;2/10/2018;2/10/2018;0;2;2;2;0;0;0;Tester3
        B1;Y1;CL1;2/7/2018;2/25/2018;2/1/2018;2/1/2018;5;25;20;20;0;0;0;Tester4
        B1;Y1;CL1;2/7/2018;2/25/2018;2/2/2018;2/2/2018;10;30;20;18;2;0;0;Tester4
        B1;Y1;CL1;2/7/2018;2/25/2018;2/3/2018;2/3/2018;0;2;2;0;2;0;0;Tester4
        B1;Y1;CL1;1/17/2018;2/25/2018;2/4/2018;2/4/2018;0;3;3;1;2;0;0;Tester4
        B1;Y1;CL1;1/17/2018;2/25/2018;2/5/2018;2/5/2018;5;32;25;20;4;1;0;Tester4
        C1;Z1;CK1;1/10/2018;2/20/2018;2/3/2018;2/3/2018;0;1;1;0;1;0;0;Tester5
        C1;Z1;CK1;1/10/2018;2/20/2018;2/4/2018;2/4/2018;0;1;1;0;1;0;0;Tester5
        C1;Z1;CK1;1/10/2018;2/20/2018;2/5/2018;2/5/2018;0;1;1;0;1;0;0;Tester5
        C1;Z1;CK1;1/10/2018;2/20/2018;2/6/2018;2/6/2018;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;Tester5
        C1;Z1;CK1;1/10/2018;2/20/2018;2/7/2018;2/7/2018;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;Tester6
        C1;Z1;CK1;1/10/2018;2/20/2018;2/8/2018;2/8/2018;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;Tester6
        C1;Z1;CK2;1/17/2018;2/18/2018;2/6/2018;2/6/2018;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;Tester6
        C1;Z1;CK2;1/17/2018;2/18/2018;2/7/2018;2/7/2018;0;2;2;0;2;0;0;Tester6
        C1;Z1;CK2;1/17/2018;2/18/2018;2/8/2018;2/8/2018;0;2;2;0;2;0;0;Tester7
        C1;Z1;CK2;1/17/2018;2/18/2018;2/9/2018;2/9/2018;0;2;2;0;2;0;0;Tester7
        C1;Z1;CK2;1/17/2018;2/18/2018;2/10/2018;2/10/2018;0;2;2;1;1;0;0;Tester7
        C1;Z1;CK2;1/17/2018;2/18/2018;2/11/2018;2/11/2018;0;2;2;2;0;0;0;Tester7""")

df = pd.read_csv(test_data, sep=";")
new_df = df.groupby(['Project', 'Release Name', 'Cycle Name', 'Cycle Start Date', 'Cycle End Date'])['Exec Date','Planned Exec Date', 'Available Test Cases', 'Planned', 'Tested', 'Passed', 'Failed', 'Blocked'].sum().reset_index()
print new_df
```

`new_df` looks like:

```
      Project Release Name Cycle Name Cycle Start Date Cycle End Date  Available Test Cases  Planned  Tested  Passed  Failed  Blocked
0          B1           Y1        CL1        1/17/2018      2/25/2018                     5       35      28      21       6        1
1          B1           Y1        CL1         2/7/2018      2/25/2018                    15       57      42      38       4        0
2          B1           Y1        CM1         2/7/2018      2/20/2018                     4       28      23      22       1        1
3          C1           Z1        CK1        1/10/2018      2/20/2018                     0        6       6       3       3        0
4          C1           Z1        CK2        1/17/2018      2/18/2018                     0       11      11       4       7        0
```

You can then do the `groupby()` again, but keep only the first occurrence. Now the missing columns will be present, since there are no ambiguity in the columns:

```
# Get first occurrence of "Exec Date" and "Planned Exec Date"
firsts = df.groupby(['Project', 'Release Name', 'Cycle Name', 'Cycle Start Date', "Cycle End Date"]).first().reset_index()
print firsts
```

`firsts` looks like:

```
      Project Release Name Cycle Name Cycle Start Date Cycle End Date Exec Date Planned Exec Date  Available Test Cases  Planned  Tested  Passed  Failed  Blocked  No Run   Tester
0          B1           Y1        CL1        1/17/2018      2/25/2018  2/4/2018          2/4/2018                     0        3       3       1       2        0       0  Tester4
1          B1           Y1        CL1         2/7/2018      2/25/2018  2/1/2018          2/1/2018                     5       25      20      20       0        0       0  Tester4
2          B1           Y1        CM1         2/7/2018      2/20/2018  2/6/2018          2/6/2018                     2       10       8       8       0        0       0  Tester3
3          C1           Z1        CK1        1/10/2018      2/20/2018  2/3/2018          2/3/2018                     0        1       1       0       1        0       0  Tester5
4          C1           Z1        CK2        1/17/2018      2/18/2018  2/6/2018          2/6/2018                     0        1       1       1       0        0       0  Tester6
```

Then merge the initial `groupby()` result (the one with the sums) with the `groupby()` results containing the missing columns:

```
# Merge in the missing columns into the result from the groupby
new_df_with_missing_columns = new_df.merge(firsts[["Project", "Release Name", "Cycle Name", "Cycle Start Date", "Cycle End Date", "Exec Date", "Planned Exec Date"]], on=["Project", "Release Name", "Cycle Name", "Cycle Start Date", "Cycle End Date"])
print new_df_with_missing_columns
```

`new_df_with_missing_columns` looks like:

```
      Project Release Name Cycle Name Cycle Start Date Cycle End Date  Available Test Cases  Planned  Tested  Passed  Failed  Blocked Exec Date Planned Exec Date
0          B1           Y1        CL1        1/17/2018      2/25/2018                     5       35      28      21       6        1  2/4/2018          2/4/2018
1          B1           Y1        CL1         2/7/2018      2/25/2018                    15       57      42      38       4        0  2/1/2018          2/1/2018
2          B1           Y1        CM1         2/7/2018      2/20/2018                     4       28      23      22       1        1  2/6/2018          2/6/2018
3          C1           Z1        CK1        1/10/2018      2/20/2018                     0        6       6       3       3        0  2/3/2018          2/3/2018
4          C1           Z1        CK2        1/17/2018      2/18/2018                     0       11      11       4       7        0  2/6/2018          2/6/2018
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and I am trying to find if we can do something like in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391969/how-to-group-pandas-dataframe-entries-by-date-in-a-non-unique-column

The difference is that this post addresses the year component of date and there are fewer columns.