# How to group dataframe by hour using timestamp with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe structure that is indexed with a timestamp:

```
    neg neu norm    pol pos date
time                        
1520353341  0.000   1.000   0.0000  0.000000    0.000   
1520353342  0.121   0.879   -0.2960 0.347851    0.000   
1520353342  0.217   0.783   -0.6124 0.465833    0.000
```

I create a date from the timestamp:

```
data_frame['date'] = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(d) for d in data_frame.time]
```

**Result:**

```
    neg neu norm    pol pos date
time                        
1520353341  0.000   1.000   0.0000  0.000000    0.000   2018-03-06 10:22:21
1520353342  0.121   0.879   -0.2960 0.347851    0.000   2018-03-06 10:22:22
1520353342  0.217   0.783   -0.6124 0.465833    0.000   2018-03-06 10:22:22
```

I want to **group by hour**, while getting the **mean** for **all the values, except the timestamp**, that should be the hour from where the group started. So **this is the result I want to archive:**

```
    neg neu norm    pol pos
time                    
1520352000  0.027989    0.893233    0.122535    0.221079    0.078779
1520355600  0.028861    0.899321    0.103698    0.209353    0.071811
```

The closest I have gotten so far has been with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391969/how-to-group-pandas-dataframe-entries-by-date-in-a-non-unique-column):

```
data = data.groupby(data.date.dt.hour).mean()
```

**Results:**

```
    neg neu norm    pol pos
date                    
0   0.027989    0.893233    0.122535    0.221079    0.078779
1   0.028861    0.899321    0.103698    0.209353    0.071811
```

But I cant figure out how to keep the timestamp that takes in account he hour where the grouby started.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I came across this gem, [`pd.DataFrame.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html), after I posted my round-to-hour solution.

```
# Construct example dataframe
times = pd.date_range('1/1/2018', periods=5, freq='25min')
values = [4,8,3,4,1]
df = pd.DataFrame({'val':values}, index=times)

# Resample by hour and calculate medians
df.resample('H').median()
```

Or you can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) if you don't want times as index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val':values, 'times':times})
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(level='times', freq='H')).median()
```

Comment: Very neat answer

Comment: These methods don't work if the data frame spans multiple days i.e. it does not ignore the date part of a datetime index. The original approach from the question `data = data.groupby(data.date.dt.hour).mean()` does that, but does indeed not preserve the hour. To preserve the hour in such a case you can pull the hour from the datetime index into a separate col before grouping: `data['hour']=data.index.hour`

Answer (score 4):

Did you try creating an hour column by:

```
data_frame['hour'] = data_frame.date.dt.hour
```

Then grouping by hour like:

```
data = data.groupby(data.hour).mean()
```

Comment: Yes, that gives me the same result I have right now. The problem is keeping/generating the timestamp for the beginning of the hour.

Answer (score 2):

You can round the timestamp column down to the nearest hour:

```
import math
df.time = [math.floor(t/3600) * 3600 for t in df.time]
```

Or even simpler, using integer division:

```
df.time = [(t//3600) * 3600 for t in df.time]
```

You can group by this column and thus preserve the timestamp.

Comment: How I didn't thought about this? This works perfectly, such a simple and elegant solution. Thanks!

Comment: If you already have a datetime index you can floor to the hour like this: `df.loc[df.index.floor('H')]` - also works with other time frequencies 'D', ...