# Group non-unique datetime column by date and sum values in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, data-processing

I have dataframe `df` as below:

```
         start_time                 end_time        count
0   2020-02-03 08:42:21.997 2020-02-03 09:34:18.737 3116
1   2020-02-03 09:34:18.837 2020-02-03 10:16:56.583 2557
2   2020-02-03 10:17:00.480 2020-02-03 13:18:51.540 10911
3   2020-02-03 13:18:51.640 2020-02-03 14:01:23.263 2551
4   2020-02-03 14:01:23.363 2020-02-03 14:43:56.977 255
```

I would like to group by the `date` only of the `start_time` column and sum all corresponding `count` values in the same day. I found a relevant answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391969/how-to-group-pandas-dataframe-entries-by-date-in-a-non-unique-column).

Using this method:

```
data.groupby(data.date.dt.year)
```

however, I received the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-7618d5285bb9> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 df.groupby(df.date.dt.year)      # Adding ['start_time'] will return 'AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'date''.
      3 
      4 
      5 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5177             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5178                 return self[name]
-> 5179             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5180 
   5181     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'date'
```

What is the problem and how can I group these non-unique datetime values in the `start_time` column by **date only** and sum the values?

---

Edit:

In fact, I was able to do it with

```
import datetime 
df['date'] = df['start_time'].dt.date       # Group by 'date' of 'datetime' column
df.groupby('date').sum()                    # Sum
```

But I'd like to know if I could do it directly, probably something more straightforward like a one-liner as shown in the answer in the aforementioned post.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html , by: mapping function, labels or list of labels

Comment: Please provide the entire error message. What did you except `data.date` to do?

Comment: @AMC Please see edited answer for complete error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super close, `datetime.dt.date` is how you access just the date potion of the datetime object (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-series-dt-date/). Try:

```py
data.groupby(data["start_time"].dt.date)["count"].sum()
```

Here is some background information about the indexing that I think you're missing:

When we write `data["start_time"]`, we are getting column `start_time` from your dataframe `data`.  An equivalent way of getting this column is to use `data.start_time`. When you try to access `data.date` (which is equivalent to `data["date"]`), we get an attribute error because your dataframe `data` does not have a column called `date`.

If the `start_time` column is of type `datettime` then it has an attribute called `dt` which has the attribute `date` which is what we are wanting to group by. We can access this through `data.start_time.dt.date` or `data["start_time"].dt.date`.

When you write `data["date"] = data["start_time"]`, you are creating a new column in your dataframe called `date` which is equal to your `start_time` column. You can now access it through `data.date` (or `data["date"]`) which is why your solution works.

Comment: you need explain you can pass a mapping function in groupby

Comment: Thanks. It worked:) Any idea how the error came about?

Comment: column date is not in your dataframe

Comment: yes, you were trying to access the date column from the dataframe with `data.date` which is equivalent to `data['date']`

Comment: first you get start_time series after you acces to the date using dt.date ...

Comment: Should I use `df.groupby(df['start_time'].date.dt.date)` then? The code returned `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'date'`

Comment: I've updated the answer to give a little more background behind how this is actually working